# How to find and update a line in Sheets? (Message Counter)

Tags: javascript, google-sheets, axios, discord, discord.js

currently I managed that as soon as someone writes a message in the chat, the bot checks whether your ID already exists in the sheet list and if not adds you to the list.

Now I want the bot to do some kind of message counter in the sheet list. What would be the best way to do this with my previous code?

Short: Bot checks that you are in the list and then it adds +1 to the message counter number ("Nachrichten" means Messages.).

You could say it's like a database that stores the number of messages from each user.

Current code:

```js
const fs = require('fs').promises;
const path = require('path');
const process = require('process');
const {authenticate} = require('@google-cloud/local-auth');
const {google} = require('googleapis');
const axios = require('axios');
const moment = require('moment');
const SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets.readonly'];

// The file token.json stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
// created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
// time.

const TOKEN_PATH = path.join(process.cwd(), 'token.json');
const CREDENTIALS_PATH = path.join(process.cwd(), 'credentials.json');

module.exports = client => {



client.on('messageCreate', async message => {
  const member = message.member

  async function loadSavedCredentialsIfExist() {
    try {
      const content = await fs.readFile(TOKEN_PATH);
      const credentials = JSON.parse(content);
      return google.auth.fromJSON(credentials);
    } catch (err) {
      return null;
    }
  }
  
  /**
   * Serializes credentials to a file comptible with GoogleAUth.fromJSON.
   *
   * @param {OAuth2Client} client
   * @return {Promise<void>}
   */
  async function saveCredentials(client) {
    const content = await fs.readFile(CREDENTIALS_PATH);
    const keys = JSON.parse(content);
    const key = keys.installed || keys.web;
    const payload = JSON.stringify({
      type: 'authorized_user',
      client_id: key.client_id,
      client_secret: key.client_secret,
      refresh_token: client.credentials.refresh_token,
    });
    await fs.writeFile(TOKEN_PATH, payload);
  }
  
  /**
   * Load or request or authorization to call APIs.
   *
   */
  async function authorize() {
    let client = await loadSavedCredentialsIfExist();
    if (client) {
      return client;
    }
    client = await authenticate({
      scopes: SCOPES,
      keyfilePath: CREDENTIALS_PATH,
    });
    if (client.credentials) {
      await saveCredentials(client);
    }
    return client;
  }
  
  /**
   * 
   * @see https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/12e_460eFvxYS5m8AMRg17uBlfEEzjpOfPqgbX0YIeEE/edit
   * @param {google.auth.OAuth2} auth The authenticated Google OAuth client.
   */
  async function listMajors(auth) {
    const sheets = google.sheets({version: 'v4', auth});
    const res = await sheets.spreadsheets.values.get({
      spreadsheetId: '12e_460eFvxYS5m8AMRg17uBlfEEzjpOfPqgbX0YIeEE',
      range: 'Liste!B2:B',
    });
    const rows = res.data.values;
     const rowsdata = res.data.values.join(', ');
    if (rowsdata.includes(`${member.id}`)) {
      // Here i need the bot edit the Message Line
     return;
    } else 
    axios.post('https://sheetdb.io/api/v1/gfycyawty283n', {
      data: {
        Name: `${member.user.tag}`,
        ID: `${member.id}`,
        Nachrichten: `1`,
        VoiceTime: "00:00:00:00",
        ServerBeigetreten: moment.utc(member.joinedAt).format('DD/MM/YY HH:MM:SS')
      }
    })
    
    
  }
  
  authorize().then(listMajors).catch(console.error);
  

  })  


};
```

[image: Sheet]

sheet afterwards:

"Nachrichten" means Messages.

The bot need to find the user ID and changes every message the "Nachrichten" Value +1 (Message counter).
[image: Sheet Finished]

Comment: Kindly include a screenshot/dummy sheet of your desired output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve it myself. Here is the finished code.

```js
const fs = require('fs').promises;
const path = require('path');
const process = require('process');
const {authenticate} = require('@google-cloud/local-auth');
const {google} = require('googleapis');
const axios = require('axios');
const moment = require('moment');
const SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets.readonly'];

// The file token.json stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
// created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
// time.

const TOKEN_PATH = path.join(process.cwd(), 'token.json');
const CREDENTIALS_PATH = path.join(process.cwd(), 'credentials.json');

let channelblacklist = ['1084311032228479047','1084310095170637845']

module.exports = client => {



client.on('messageCreate', async message => {
  const member = message.member

  async function loadSavedCredentialsIfExist() {
    try {
      const content = await fs.readFile(TOKEN_PATH);
      const credentials = JSON.parse(content);
      return google.auth.fromJSON(credentials);
    } catch (err) {
      return null;
    }
  }
  
  /**
   * Serializes credentials to a file comptible with GoogleAUth.fromJSON.
   *
   * @param {OAuth2Client} client
   * @return {Promise<void>}
   */
  async function saveCredentials(client) {
    const content = await fs.readFile(CREDENTIALS_PATH);
    const keys = JSON.parse(content);
    const key = keys.installed || keys.web;
    const payload = JSON.stringify({
      type: 'authorized_user',
      client_id: key.client_id,
      client_secret: key.client_secret,
      refresh_token: client.credentials.refresh_token,
    });
    await fs.writeFile(TOKEN_PATH, payload);
  }
  
  /**
   * Load or request or authorization to call APIs.
   *
   */
  async function authorize() {
    let client = await loadSavedCredentialsIfExist();
    if (client) {
      return client;
    }
    client = await authenticate({
      scopes: SCOPES,
      keyfilePath: CREDENTIALS_PATH,
    });
    if (client.credentials) {
      await saveCredentials(client);
    }
    return client;
  }
  
  /**
   * 
   * @see https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/12e_460eFvxYS5m8AMRg17uBlfEEzjpOfPqgbX0YIeEE/edit
   * @param {google.auth.OAuth2} auth The authenticated Google OAuth client.
   */
  async function listMajors(auth) {
    const sheets = google.sheets({version: 'v4', auth});
    const res = await sheets.spreadsheets.values.get({
      spreadsheetId: '12e_460eFvxYS5m8AMRg17uBlfEEzjpOfPqgbX0YIeEE',
      range: 'Liste!A2:E', // A2:E umfasst alle Spalten, in denen wir Daten haben
    });
    const rows = res.data.values;
     const rowsdata = res.data.values.join(', ');
    if (rowsdata.includes(`${member.id}`)) {
      if (channelblacklist.includes(message.channel.id)) return;
      const index = rows.findIndex(row => row[1] === member.id);
      const row = rows[index];
      const nachrichten = parseInt(row[2], 10) + 1;
      const updateRange = `Liste!C${index + 2}`; // Wir fügen 2 hinzu, um die Kopfzeile zu überspringen
      await sheets.spreadsheets.values.update({
        spreadsheetId: '12e_460eFvxYS5m8AMRg17uBlfEEzjpOfPqgbX0YIeEE',
        range: updateRange,
        valueInputOption: 'RAW',
        requestBody: {
          values: [[nachrichten]],
        },
      });
     return;
    } else 
    axios.post('https://sheetdb.io/api/v1/gfycyawty283n', {
      data: {
        Name: `${member.user.tag}`,
        ID: `${member.id}`,
        Nachrichten: `1`,
        VoiceTime: "00:00:00:00",
        ServerBeigetreten: moment.utc(member.joinedAt).format('DD/MM/YY HH:MM:SS')
      }
    })
    
    
  }
  
  authorize().then(listMajors).catch(console.error);
  

  })  


};
```